# Could a Pyrrhonic Skeptic Procedurally know?

Tags: knowledge, skepticism

is the concept of Procedural Knowledge, inconsistent with Pyrrhonic Skepticism?

i ask this as, it does not seem that Procedural Knowledge coincides with the model of Knowledge espoused by Pyrrhonic Skeptics, and thus it seems Pyrrhonic Skeptics could "know" in a Procedural Knowledge sense, but not in a Declarative Knowledge sense?

Comment: Since they could write and talk they did have procedural knowledge, i.e. skills. Indeed, on some conceptions [belief is not a requirement](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis/#BeliCond) even for propositional knowledge, we do often act on claims we doubt (which happen to be true and justified, unbeknownst to us). They must have had declarative knowledge of this sort too.

Comment: @Conifold But applying the conceptions of propositional knowledge, that require belief, they wouldn't have declarative knowledge? "They must have had declarative knowledge of this sort too" Even if not requiring belief, how would they jusitify it?

Comment: They need not do it, it is enough that it is acquired through a reliable process, for example.